# Azure Git Deployment Failing - Selectnodeversion.js

Tags: node.js, git, azure, deployment, jenkins

I am having trouble deploying to azure through my git hosted on Azure, the build through JenkinsCI will pass fine but once it tries to deploy Azure throws this;

```
 Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling node.js deployment.
KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
 An error has occurred during web site deployment.
undefined:5
<<<<<<< HEAD
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\28.30730.1063\bin\scripts\selectNodeVersion.js:119:44)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Any help is really appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Even if I'm late to the party, that token looks like an unresolved git merge conflict (perhaps in the deployment script).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a possible Kudu issue (the git deployment engine in Azure). It would be best if you can open an issue on https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu so we can investigate.

Please include additional details about your repo. If you are able to share a small repo that demonstrates the problem, it would be ideal. Thanks!

Comment: hi i have opened a issue there. Link : https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2192