# Azure webservice Deployment Error

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy the changes to the azure web service but weird error of Unmerged file in the deployment scripts from Azure is coming.

It says that the code is pushed to the repository but unable to deploy.

[image]

Comment: Found a similar issue posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25400621/azure-git-deployment-failing-selectnodeversion-js) just for your reference. Could be a kudu issue but not confirmed yet.

Comment: Yes, looks the same, and also tracked by https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1947. But we never got any repro or follow-up so it was unsolved. Please follow up on GitHub issue to help investigation.

Comment: Yes, it seems the same issue. Any idea how to get it resolved?

Comment: The issue was from my side, was able to track down the issue after looking at the ProjectKudu issue https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1947. It was coming because of unmerged package.json file.